# Getting cell value by row name and column name from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Let's say I have the following data frame

```
     name             age     favorite_color  grade
0    Willard Morris   20           blue     88
1       Al Jennings   19           blue     92
2      Omar Mullins   22         yellow     95
3  Spencer McDaniel   21          green     70
```

And I'm trying to get the grade for Omar which is "95"

it can be easily obtained using

```
ddf = df.loc[[2], ['grade']]
print(ddf)
```

However, I want to use his name "Omar" instead of using the raw index "2".

Is it possible?

I tried the following syntax but it didn't work

```
ddf = df.loc[['Omar Mullins'], ['grade']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ddf = df[df['name'] == 'Omar Mullins']['grade']
```

to output the `grade` values.

Instead:

```
ddf = df[df['name'] == 'Omar Mullins']
```

will output the full row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! wish I asked earlier to save that wasted 1 hour :')

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Cheers!